# NavDirection cast issue since I have upgraded to gradle 4.2.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I have upgraded my project to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
```

I have a static method in a utils File :

```
public static void launchFragment(BaseFragment fragment, NavDirections directions) {
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment).navigate(directions);
}
```

Since this morning if I'm using

```
 ActivityUtils.launchFragment(this, ProfileFragmentDirections.accountAction());
```

It's good but if I'm calling an action with parameters like this one

```
   ActivityUtils.launchFragment(this, MainHostFragmentDirections.webAction(getString(R.string.info_moderation), WebFragment.MODERATION));
```

I have an error on the IDE

```
Cannot resolve method 'launchFragment(fr.tmly.androidapp.ui.main.activity.MainActivity, fr.tmly.androidapp.ui.main.fragment.MainHostFragmentDirections.@androidx.annotation.NonNull WebAction)'
```

The error say that

```
fr.tmly.androidapp.ui.main.fragment.MainHostFragmentDirections.@androidx.annotation.NonNull WebAction
```

is not a NavDirections class, but I can build compile and run the project and if I check in debugger

[image: good type]
as you can see it's an instance of NavDirection

The solution to get ride of this error is to add (NavDirections) cast like this

```
ActivityUtils.launchFragment(this, (NavDirections) MainHostFragmentDirections.webAction(
                        getString(R.string.info_moderation), WebFragment.MODERATION));
```

But I'm using this method everywhere in My app and I dont want to add the manual cast everywhere, what can I do ? Before the gradle upgrade I haven't this error.